# Display just one file per match using grep (in a shellscript)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

How do I limit grep's output to just one line per file?

(Since this is part of a shellscript function, I can use everything, but I'm too nooby to figure out how to pipe the specific parts the right way.)

The function I'm trying to write is basically "Given a string, display every file (in this directory and all subdirectories), which contains it and display a list of those files as clickable links"

(btw. could you hint me to scripts/commands, which do something like this?)

If you are interested: The functions in .bashrc are these:
(And should be used like: "where foobar")

```
function where(){
    grep -rHoiIm1 "$@" | cut -d":" -f1-1 | asURL
}

function asURL() {
    PREFIX="file://$(pwd)/";
    sed "s*^*$PREFIX*" |
    sed 's/ /%20/g'; 
}
```

Comment: You already have `-m1` in your grep arguments (albeit in a cryptic way).  Doesn't that do exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: I was thinking the same, but it kept displaying some files multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only interested in the *paths* of matching files, use the `-l` / `--files-with-matches` option:

```
function where(){
  grep -riIl "$@" | asURL
}
```

Note that I've omitted several options that don't apply anymore once you use `-l`.

As an aside: while your `asUrl()` function will work in simple cases, it's not fully robust and can result in invalid URLs. Aside from that, there's no reason for *two* invocations of `sed`; simply string the two `s` calls together in a single script, separated with `;`.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks. Could you give me an example when the asUrl breaks? Do you know of a function/script, which does what I try to achieve but is properly working?

Comment: @Rian: Glad to hear it; any filename containing characters other than spaces that also must be escaped in URLs will result in an invalid URL, such as `%`, `&`, or `ö` (non-ASCII char.).

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-l` option to grep to tell it to output file names only.

From the [grep man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

> -l
>
> --files-with-matches
>
> Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from 
>   which output would normally have been printed. The scanning of each file
>   stops on the first match. (-l is specified by POSIX.)

Comment: This was the solution, thanks! Although I feel dumb now. I guess I've erased -l from my mind, cause it does not work with -n (while -Hn is fine)

Comment: No need to feel dumb, everybody starts solving a problem with the tools and tricks they know best. The -l option happens to be about the only one I use for grep regularly other than -i.